# Approximate formula for the series: $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{k^x}{(k!)^x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, interpolation, hypergeometric-function

I found that this series:
$$S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{k^x}{(k!)^x}$$ can be very well approximated in this way:
$$S(x)=\dfrac{1}{\left(a+b\exp(cx)\right)^d}$$
with: $a=0.1876$, $b=-0.1895$, $c=-0.6567$, $d=0.4141$. I know the function $S(x)$ can be obtained in an uneasy way using hypergeometric functions.
Is there some deep reason for this result? Thanks.

Comment: You know you can simplify the expression to $\sum_{k=0} \frac{1}{(k!)^x}$ ?

Comment: I do know how you could obtain the result using hypergeometric functions; please let me know. Concerning your fit, it is effectively very good which means that you found a nice expression to fit. Using four parameters to be tuned gives a lot of flexibility and let me congratulate you for that. However, if you look at the residuals, you will notice that they are all on the same side for $x>10$ and I am surprized. I shall try to look at the problem. Again, it is nice. By the way, what range of $x$ did you use for the fit ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I used $1\le x\le 10$

Comment: For $x=2$, your expression becomes $I_0(2)$, where ***I*** is the [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

Comment: Could you tell me how to arrive to an  hypergeometric function ?

Comment: @Lucian. Do you see a way to get a closed form (even if awful) ? Thanks and cheers :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: For natural values of *x* we have $S(x)=~_0F_{x-1}\Big(\{\}~;\{1,1,\ldots,1\}~;1\Big)$.

Comment: @Lucian. Could you by chance give me the syntax for this in Mathematica ? I would like to try something if I can get an access to Mma. Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: ``HypergeometricPFQ[{}, {1, 1}, 1]``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For large $x$ the first two terms will dominate so you get the asymptotic behavior

$$S(x) \sim 2 + \frac{1}{2^x}$$

Your approximation on the other hand has

$$f(x) \sim \frac{1}{a^d}\left(1 - \frac{db}{a}e^{cx}\right) \approx 1.99 + \frac{0.836}{2^{0.94 x}}$$

If you consider $S(x)-2$ then the approximation you have found is really not that good for large $x$ (in terms of the relative error of $S(x)-2$).

If we consider $x\to 0$ will also see that the approximation is not that good. For intermediate values of $x$ it does fit very well, but you have four parameters to play with so that should not come as a big surprise.

Answer (score 5):

I played with your formula and I generated data for integer values of $x$ between $1$ and $12$ but I took into account the fact that $S(x)$ goes to $\infty$ when $x$ goes to $0$. On the other side, $S(x)$ goes to $2$ if $x$ goes to $\infty$. All of that made that, by analogy with your work, I used $$S(x)=\dfrac{2}{\left(1-\exp(cx)\right)^d}$$ for which I obtained $c=-0.661508$ and $d=0.422774$ which are very similar to your. However, the residuals I obtained seem to be better conditioned than your and they become almost unsignificant for large values of $x$.

**Added later to this answer**

If we force the equation to produce $S(1)=e$, we can have a quite good model using  $$d=\frac{\log \left(\frac{e}{2}\right)}{\log \left(1-e^c\right)}$$ and only one parameter $c$ is left for the regression. Moreover $c=-\frac{2}{3}$ seems to be a pretty good approximation which makes the model totally parameter free.

It would be very nice if some one could justify this.

Comment: Ok, I see your approximation is better than mine. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. You did the work and I just tried to polish a little. Cheers :)